# DHCP not working on clients connected to Nexus 3048 but works on SVI

Tags: vlan, dhcp, cisco-nexus, nx-os

I've a strange problem with a pair of Nexus 3048 Switches in a vPC configuration.

Since the core are still under implementation we've hit an strange issue: clients can't get IP addresses from the DHCP server, but the SVI can get an address from the DHCP server.

The DHCP server is plugged on another switch, but the connection is made on one interface on the first Nexus and the interface have this configuration:

```
interface Ethernet1/23
  description "Untag 37 directly from 3COM 4200G"
  switchport access vlan 37
  spanning-tree port type edge
  spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
  no shutdown
```

There's no Layer 3 routing happening inside the Nexus. It's plain Layer 2 networking, which should work without any hassle.

The curious thing is that the SVI can get the IP address from the DHCP server. The same SVI on the second Nexus cant't get the address either.

I've done the following tests to debug the problem:

- Created a vPC with both switches and tried DHCP from a Port Channel enabled host.
- Plugged a host on orphaned port on first on the first Nexus and then on the second one.
- Changed the port from trunk to access, like the configuration above.
- Used a different DHCP server on the port.

In all cases DHCP still does not work. But there's connectivity, because I can set manual IP addresses in all cases, and everything works as it should. Orphaned ports, trunked ports, port channels, etc.

So it's definitely something on the switch dropping the DHCP packets. There's no DHCP features enabled on Nexus, só it can't be any security problem:

```
core1# sh feature | grep -i dhcp 
dhcp                   1         disabled
```

I even used tried `tcpdump` on client machines to see if the DHCP packages are sent and I can confirm they are being sent. On the switches I tried some debugging with `ethanalyzer` and what I see is a lot of "DHCP Discover" requests without any answer. Only the SVI DHCP request of the first switch appears to be working. Here is a snippet:

```
2017-06-03 23:38:49.617523      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x9697d613
2017-06-03 23:39:05.254997      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x9697d613
2017-06-03 23:39:17.119522      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x9697d613
2017-06-03 23:39:24.317940      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x9697d613
2017-06-03 23:39:35.687699      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x9697d613
2017-06-03 23:40:02.900892      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xd7c4ba70
2017-06-03 23:40:10.946648      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xd7c4ba70
2017-06-03 23:40:21.071947      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xd7c4ba70
2017-06-03 23:40:35.114446      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xd7c4ba70
2017-06-03 23:40:49.380103      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xd7c4ba70
2017-06-03 23:44:05.282352 146.164.37.11 -> 146.164.36.50 DHCP DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x592f3e7a
2017-06-03 23:44:05.283041 146.164.36.50 -> 146.164.37.11 DHCP DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x592f3e7a
2017-06-03 23:46:03.509158      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x75bda403
2017-06-03 23:46:11.942522      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x75bda403
2017-06-03 23:46:26.965735      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x75bda403
2017-06-03 23:46:38.008869      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x75bda403
2017-06-03 23:46:45.221171      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x75bda403
2017-06-03 23:46:57.352744      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x75bda403
2017-06-03 23:47:09.395484      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x13487f09
2017-06-03 23:47:16.159521      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x13487f09
2017-06-03 23:47:32.450281      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x13487f09
2017-06-03 23:47:40.803963      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x13487f09
2017-06-03 23:48:00.665313      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x13487f09
```

The report was generated with this command:

```
ethanalyzer local interface inband capture-filter "port 67 or port 68" limit-captured-frames 0
```

This is really frustrating, since DHCP is dead simple and it should work without any hassle. The DHCP server in question is the isc-dhcpd-server running on Debian 7 Wheezy and it's on production, serving a lot of different subnets, so it's working as it should.

What I'm missing? There's something that should be enabled on Nexus? Perhaps some kind of default ACL's blocking the DHCP traffic?

To be more precise here's a drawing of the topology:

```
+-------------+      +-------------+      +-----------+
| DHCP Server | ---> | 3COM Switch | ---> | Nexus #01 | <--- Random Host
+-------------+      +-------------+      +-----------+
                                               || 
                                          +-----------+
                                          | Nexus #02 | <--- Random Host
                                          +-----------+
```

The DHCP Server have the following network configuration:

```
IP: 146.164.36.50/24
GW: 146.164.36.36
```

On the 3COM switch there are rules for DHCP relaying from different subnets, configured in the following way:

```
#
 dhcp-server 1 ip  146.164.36.50  
 dhcp-server detect

vlan 1
 description Management
 igmp-snooping enable
#
vlan 10
 description Servers
#
vlan 37
#
vlan 100
 description Acesso
#
interface Vlan-interface1
 ip address 10.3.12.1 255.255.255.0 
 dhcp-server 1
#
interface Vlan-interface10
 ip address 146.164.36.36 255.255.255.0  
#
interface Vlan-interface37
 ip address 146.164.37.1 255.255.255.0 
 dhcp-server 1
```

Everything is working on the DHCP relay side, since anything connected to the Vlan-interface 37 works as expected, doesn't matter if it's a random host of a switch with others hosts attached.

And finally here is the full Nexus #01 configuration. The second one have similar configuration.

```
core1# sh run

!Command: show running-config
!Time: Sun Jun  4 00:05:49 2017

version 7.0(3)I2(2d)
hostname core1
vdc core1 id 1
  limit-resource vlan minimum 16 maximum 4094
  limit-resource vrf minimum 2 maximum 4096
  limit-resource port-channel minimum 0 maximum 104
  limit-resource u4route-mem minimum 128 maximum 128
  limit-resource u6route-mem minimum 96 maximum 96
  limit-resource m4route-mem minimum 58 maximum 58
  limit-resource m6route-mem minimum 8 maximum 8

cfs eth distribute
feature interface-vlan
feature lacp
feature vpc
feature lldp
feature vtp

username admin password 5 !  role network-admin
username ferrao password 5 !  role network-admin
username ferrao sshkey ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDM+cCPmszkpw0DMeOYLSWoGAHd4POhfQJ5llIu6uJ2CX0VNSzRDGIr01fMQKvjTcsqX2EoF2xpO8nj8XZoSNUetwC+G
J3dBWKxFnZ+AFCzT4pTOWDmGKr0k75r7sU2yqlkgAuVryWB/Y5e8QIyVcaVyrbUGqDQBIA6f9lqF3pYivzTU1XLiz5sQNv/7DSvHVBA9MiFycs4PMhqh89YzW+QU2H4v3zWVTXd/FyXr3Pp3wvkWu1NY
GviIx3LMg9S3mydk2i5MUddoOPPfHQKtrOiBpXApZwegRGOHVqvkEfn6GLNkCXBT151vRRVKGeUbiZyg0RLUnuE61UbpCUvEXtWxH2EHUiYDWzFhZVPvE451meyYdr0mFEGFaW97mnjGNmYle9sx5UmW
5r3f/KJHdOzDgAGWwPN9H9AdbXSLtycovJGhglJ8nLouTz3CZPFnsAvOrHx/svJnLTJU1LJDJanFVqMgTpnXDcjW/8fCyVgyZcPHjQnY+VyUM/4zYPceEA+ghKgBJMyBQ0RC+SxdiC9wrYK/urw/GxNj
VY6upfpmzsfetIK07OTuucaohHTg5Oo3gIJhQ8Vgi4souxs0+rrskhW4ztxw1VI3UXiUGotmAh6VWFyoIuG4a+Z8fPi3PZ3NyC90Byalmz5lp1SXBjcTeYwUvpCQGKxdkhISl+Bjw==
username heliocm password 5 !  role network-admin
username heliocm sshkey rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDTtokq0PacXStKYhfZy8KMIkCugdzCAkc7fDtK+PCjscrqL41otfV/WjOXg3qftJUswx1Ggt5qvbSGx452fLwAxGoXWsJn
ohwbPwwkqRG1kpVyxYt3xIgw2EkJsbrm8T4PuajfqPBJFgZU3opMH1msRmQN+WrRyZhvZPf6wE4Ahx4nrzxo6Tmgzf6v9xUZQ1RlAMODzUfaM054nKh/fJz+A9L281Ra6vHmYuLoDNzR4MQxCVPiZfUA
gwIWLcVStdWhQ3a5i/bzbNyp3+5MgtO0BC0Q5kSZD3SGkuM8vsQTn+l6Zqi2nqOX7bfdrrqIQa8XAidyoQOsthKTI21SQGO6XUI8sSPCwuNKGrbHDLqX0+0xVdUsDupZ9lPX9T737YIvefksFHVX9lgZ
YcfxG3LRyDV6vqaDRZRq8bOmFO/nMConXxUbIJ/lJqKiR/x9yS7wV3Ja+l6v5ObOV9g9/vKP1tde1uyoJ8Wd08HtENAibEAExPhJhc12O0fpi7ZbrjEoJj6n7kHdRHcGvtpXysN3n7MkVR+xSxxZFAYX
AHyp/yfR6y5QSVJvH4efnSLRRtZN3X2R0mJhT2icQpmueVaxCHi4gCSGnCZIP8IrLdy0JxR9UFMt0B92n3aVjTJ1he2nKOmXPbUntFMT1kkunWTFPK85hPLDp5G+4IZaIv5bww==
ssh login-attempts 5

ssh key rsa 2048 
no ip domain-lookup
ip domain-name cc.if.ufrj.br
ip name-server 146.164.36.15
spanning-tree mode mst
system default switchport shutdown
no service unsupported-transceiver
ip access-list copp-system-acl-eigrp
  10 permit eigrp any 224.0.0.10/32 
ipv6 access-list copp-system-acl-eigrp6
  10 permit eigrp any ff02::a/128 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-icmp
  10 permit icmp any any 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-igmp
  10 permit igmp any any 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-ntp
  10 permit udp any any eq ntp 
  20 permit udp any eq ntp any 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-pimreg
  10 permit pim any any 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-ping
  10 permit icmp any any echo 
  20 permit icmp any any echo-reply 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-routingproto1
  10 permit tcp any gt 1024 any eq bgp 
  20 permit tcp any eq bgp any gt 1024 
  30 permit udp any 224.0.0.0/24 eq rip 
  40 permit tcp any gt 1024 any eq 639 
  50 permit tcp any eq 639 any gt 1024 
  70 permit ospf any any 
  80 permit ospf any 224.0.0.5/32 
  90 permit ospf any 224.0.0.6/32 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-routingproto2
  10 permit udp any 224.0.0.0/24 eq 1985 
  20 permit 112 any 224.0.0.0/24 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-snmp
  10 permit udp any any eq snmp 
  20 permit udp any any eq snmptrap 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-ssh
  10 permit tcp any any eq 22 
  20 permit tcp any eq 22 any 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-stftp
  10 permit udp any any eq tftp 
  20 permit udp any any eq 1758 
  30 permit udp any eq tftp any 
  40 permit udp any eq 1758 any 
  50 permit tcp any any eq 115 
  60 permit tcp any eq 115 any 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-tacacsradius
  10 permit tcp any any eq tacacs 
  20 permit tcp any eq tacacs any 
  30 permit udp any any eq 1812 
  40 permit udp any any eq 1813 
  50 permit udp any any eq 1645 
  60 permit udp any any eq 1646 
  70 permit udp any eq 1812 any 
  80 permit udp any eq 1813 any 
  90 permit udp any eq 1645 any 
  100 permit udp any eq 1646 any 
ip access-list copp-system-acl-telnet
  10 permit tcp any any eq telnet 
  20 permit tcp any any eq 107 
  30 permit tcp any eq telnet any 
  40 permit tcp any eq 107 any 
ipv6 access-list copp-system-acl-v6routingProto2
  10 permit udp any ff02::66/128 eq 2029 
  20 permit udp any ff02::fb/128 eq 5353 
  30 permit 112 any ff02::12/128 
ipv6 access-list copp-system-acl-v6routingproto1
  10 permit 89 any ff02::5/128 
  20 permit 89 any ff02::6/128 
  30 permit udp any ff02::9/128 eq 521 
ip access-list copp-system-dhcp-relay
  10 permit udp any eq bootps any eq bootps 
class-map type qos match-all iscsi
  match cos 4
policy-map type qos iscsi
  class iscsi
    set qos-group 4
  class class-default
class-map type network-qos iscsi
  match qos-group 4
policy-map type network-qos iscsi
  class type network-qos iscsi
    mtu 1500
    pause no-drop
  class type network-qos class-default
    mtu 1500
policy-map type network-qos jumbo
  class type network-qos class-default
    mtu 9216
system qos
  service-policy type network-qos iscsi
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-icmp
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-icmp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-ntp
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-ntp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-arp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-bfd
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-bpdu
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-dai
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-default
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-dhcpreq
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-dhcpresp
  match access-group name copp-system-dhcp-relay
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-dpss
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-eigrp
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-eigrp
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-eigrp6
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-glean
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-igmp
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-igmp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-ipmcmiss
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-l2switched
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-l3destmiss
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-l3mtufail
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-l3slowpath
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-mpls
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-pimautorp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-pimreg
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-pimreg
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-ping
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-ping
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-ptp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-routingProto1
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-routingproto1
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-v6routingproto1
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-routingProto2
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-routingproto2
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-selfIp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-ttl1
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-v6routingProto2
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-v6routingProto2
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-s-vxlan
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-snmp
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-snmp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-ssh
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-ssh
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-stftp
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-stftp
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-tacacsradius
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-tacacsradius
class-map type control-plane match-any copp-telnet
  match access-group name copp-system-acl-telnet
policy-map type control-plane copp-system-policy 
  class copp-s-default
    police pps 400 
  class copp-s-l2switched
    police pps 200 
  class copp-s-ping
    police pps 100 
  class copp-s-l3destmiss
    police pps 100 
  class copp-s-glean
    police pps 500 
  class copp-s-selfIp
    police pps 500 
  class copp-s-l3mtufail
    police pps 100 
  class copp-s-ttl1
    police pps 100 
  class copp-s-ipmcmiss
    police pps 400 
  class copp-s-l3slowpath
    police pps 100 
  class copp-s-dhcpreq
    police pps 300 
  class copp-s-dhcpresp
    police pps 300 
  class copp-s-dai
    police pps 300 
  class copp-s-igmp
    police pps 400 
  class copp-s-eigrp
    police pps 200 
  class copp-s-pimreg
    police pps 200 
  class copp-s-pimautorp
    police pps 200 
  class copp-s-routingProto2
    police pps 1300 
  class copp-s-v6routingProto2
    police pps 1300 
  class copp-s-routingProto1
    police pps 1000 
  class copp-s-arp
    police pps 200 
  class copp-s-ptp
    police pps 1000 
  class copp-s-vxlan
    police pps 1000 
  class copp-s-bfd
    police pps 350 
  class copp-s-bpdu
    police pps 12000 
  class copp-s-dpss
    police pps 1000 
  class copp-s-mpls
    police pps 100 
  class copp-icmp
    police pps 200 
  class copp-telnet
    police pps 500 
  class copp-ssh
    police pps 500 
  class copp-snmp
    police pps 500 
  class copp-ntp
    police pps 100 
  class copp-tacacsradius
    police pps 400 
  class copp-stftp
    police pps 400 
control-plane
  service-policy input copp-system-policy 
vtp domain cc.if.ufrj.br
snmp-server contact "Vinicius Ferrao <ferrao@cc.if.ufrj.br>"
snmp-server location "Computacao Central IF/UFRJ - CT/A-312"
snmp-server user admin network-admin auth md5 0x4f0d470b1ab6ab111b4b82962ec368f0 priv 0x4f0d470b1ab6ab111b4b82962ec368f0 localizedkey
snmp-server user ferrao network-admin auth md5 0xeab88c5301991d27d34983cf480d49ef priv 0xeab88c5301991d27d34983cf480d49ef localizedkey
rmon event 1 log trap public description FATAL(1) owner PMON@FATAL
rmon event 2 log trap public description CRITICAL(2) owner PMON@CRITICAL
rmon event 3 log trap public description ERROR(3) owner PMON@ERROR
rmon event 4 log trap public description WARNING(4) owner PMON@WARNING
rmon event 5 log trap public description INFORMATION(5) owner PMON@INFO
ntp server 146.164.48.5 use-vrf management

vlan 1
vlan 7
  name MGMT-IQ
vlan 11
  name iSCSI-MPIO1
vlan 12
  name iSCSI-MPIO2
vlan 29
  name SRV-IQ
vlan 30
  name Labs-IQ
vlan 36
  name SRV-IF
vlan 37
  name Unused37
vlan 40
  name Unused40
vlan 136
  name Access-IF
vlan 146
  name SRV-CC
vlan 172
  name Access-IQ
vlan 312
  name MGMT-IF
vlan 666
  name LIG
spanning-tree port type edge bpduguard default
spanning-tree mst 0-1 priority 24576
spanning-tree mst configuration
  name cc
  revision 1
  instance 1 vlan 2-4094
vrf context management
  ip route 0.0.0.0/0 146.164.36.1
vrf context vpc-peer-keepalive
no system urpf disable
no port-channel load-balance resilient

vpc domain 1
  peer-switch
  role priority 1
  system-priority 1000
  peer-keepalive destination 172.31.2.2 source 172.31.2.1 vrf vpc-peer-keepalive
  auto-recovery
  ipv6 nd synchronize
  ip arp synchronize


interface Vlan1

interface Vlan37
  no shutdown
  ip address dhcp

interface Vlan136

interface port-channel25
  description XenServer #1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  vpc 25

interface port-channel27
  description XenServer #2
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  vpc 27

interface port-channel29
  description XenServer #3
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  vpc 29

interface port-channel31
  description XenServer #4
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  vpc 31

interface port-channel33
  description XenServer #5
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  vpc 33

interface port-channel47
  description vPC Peer-link Keepalive
  no switchport
  vrf member vpc-peer-keepalive
  ip address 172.31.2.1/30

interface port-channel51
  description vPC Peer-link
  switchport mode trunk
  spanning-tree port type network
  speed 10000
  vpc peer-link

interface Ethernet1/1

interface Ethernet1/2

interface Ethernet1/3

interface Ethernet1/4

interface Ethernet1/5

interface Ethernet1/6

interface Ethernet1/7

interface Ethernet1/8

interface Ethernet1/9

interface Ethernet1/10

interface Ethernet1/11

interface Ethernet1/12

interface Ethernet1/13

interface Ethernet1/14

interface Ethernet1/15

interface Ethernet1/16

interface Ethernet1/17

interface Ethernet1/18

interface Ethernet1/19

interface Ethernet1/20

interface Ethernet1/21

interface Ethernet1/22
  description "Teste DHCP"
  switchport access vlan 37
  spanning-tree port type edge
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/23
  description "Untag 37 direto 3COM"
  switchport access vlan 37
  spanning-tree port type edge
  spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/24
  description Uplink Temporario IF
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 36,136,312
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  spanning-tree bpdufilter enable

interface Ethernet1/25
  description XenServer #1 Interface #1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  channel-group 25 mode active
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/26
  description XenServer iSCSI #1 Interface #1
  switchport access vlan 11
  spanning-tree port type edge
  service-policy type qos input iscsi
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/27
  description XenServer #2 Interface #1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  channel-group 27 mode active
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/28
  description XenServer iSCSI #2 Interface #1
  switchport access vlan 11
  spanning-tree port type edge
  service-policy type qos input iscsi
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/29
  description XenServer #3 Interface #1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  channel-group 29 mode active
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/30
  description XenServer iSCSI #3 Interface #1
  switchport access vlan 11
  spanning-tree port type edge
  service-policy type qos input iscsi
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/31
  description XenServer #4 Interface #1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  channel-group 31 mode active
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/32
  description XenServer iSCSI #4 Interface #1
  switchport access vlan 11
  spanning-tree port type edge
  service-policy type qos input iscsi
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/33
  description XenServer #5 Interface #1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 37
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 29,36-37,40,136,146,312
  channel-group 33 mode active
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/34
  description XenServer iSCSI #5 Interface #1
  switchport access vlan 11
  spanning-tree port type edge
  service-policy type qos input iscsi
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/35

interface Ethernet1/36

interface Ethernet1/37

interface Ethernet1/38

interface Ethernet1/39

interface Ethernet1/40

interface Ethernet1/41

interface Ethernet1/42

interface Ethernet1/43

interface Ethernet1/44

interface Ethernet1/45

interface Ethernet1/46

interface Ethernet1/47
  description vPC Peer-link Keepalive Interface #1
  no switchport
  channel-group 47

interface Ethernet1/48
  description vPC Peer-link Keepalive Interface #2
  no switchport
  channel-group 47

interface Ethernet1/49

interface Ethernet1/50
  description Storage iSCSI Interface #1
  switchport access vlan 11
  spanning-tree port type edge
  service-policy type qos input iscsi

interface Ethernet1/51
  description vPC Peer-link Interface #1
  switchport mode trunk
  channel-group 51 mode active
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet1/52
  description vPC Peer-link Interface #2
  switchport mode trunk
  channel-group 51 mode active
  no shutdown

interface mgmt0
  vrf member management
  ip address 146.164.36.89/24
line console
line vty
boot nxos bootflash:/nxos.7.0.3.I2.2d.bin 
ip route 0.0.0.0/0 146.164.37.1
```

Comment: You do not provide enough information to answer the question. You need to edit your question to include a better description of how the network is connected, and the full switch configurations, otherwise we are just guessing, which is off-topic here.

Comment: It's a simple topology, with two switches, a DHCP server and randomly attached hosts. I've described this on the text. I haven't dumped the full switch configuration because it would look like spam, but I'll do this.

Comment: If your DHCP server is serving multiple subnets, then the network topology is not as simple as you make it out to be. It is probably connected to a single VLAN, and there are DHCP relays to the various VLANs.

Comment: There are any recommendation of remote text service or a way to raise the limit of 30k characters on the main post? Because I can't post both Nexus configurations.

Comment: No. To which VLAN is the DHCP server connected, and where are the DHCP relays?

Comment: I've added the DHCP relay topology and configuration on the 3COM switch. Hope it's enough information. If something is still needed please, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59843/discussion-between-vinicius-ferrao-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Already provided my own answer. Was a bug on NX-OS software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out. After four working days wasted, it was a bug on the NX-OS firmware 7.0(3)I2(2d).

After upgrading to the latest recommended version 7.0(3)I4(6) the DHCP packets started flowing normally.

Here's the link to the Cisco website: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/release/70346/n3k_70346_nxos_rn.html

Answer (score -2):

Remove this command

no system urpf disable

Comment: Please elaborate: why do you think that would help, or what does that configuration address?